# How to prevent page changing in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to validate empty inputs in kendo grid columns. I want to validate current page before you can go to a different page. My problem is I can´t prevent page changing when I get empty inputs.

```
$(function () {       
    bindPaging();        
});


function bindPaging() {
  var grid = $('#paramsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
  var pager = grid.pager;
  pager.bind('change', onPageChange);
}


function onPageChange(e) {
    var empty = $("#paramsGrid").find("input").filter(function () {
        return this.value === "" || this.value === "null";
    });
    if (empty && empty.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < empty.length; i++) {
            $("#" + empty[i].id).addClass("input-validation-error");
        }
        e.preventDefault();        
    }   

}
```

that "e.preventDefault" is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution. The event has to be "pageChange" not "change". So this is correct code:

pager.bind('pageChange', onPageChange);

instead of:

pager.bind('change', onPageChange);

Comment: That was a good find, although it doesn't seem to appear in the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/pager#events) - it might be safer to use the grid's `page` event, which is officially supported

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `e.preventDefault();`as a first line of the function.

```
function onPageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Pull this line as a first line of code in the function.
    var empty = $("#paramsGrid").find("input").filter(function () {
        return this.value === "" || this.value === "null";
    });
    if (empty && empty.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < empty.length; i++) {
            $("#" + empty[i].id).addClass("input-validation-error");
        }        
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the grid's [page](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/page) event

> Fired when the user is about change the current page index of DataSource via the pager UI.
>
> The event handler function context (available via the this keyword) will be set to the widget instance.

```
function bindPaging() {
  var grid = $('#paramsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
  grid.bind('page', onPageChange);
}
```